# Cordova Push notification event "notificationReceived" doesn't fire until I click on the notification toast

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am implementing push notifications for a hybrid app in ionic using Cordova, the problem I am facing is that CordovaPush plugin has a notification event "notificationReceived" but this doesn't get fired until unless I click on the notification toast in the notification bar. Please note that I am able to receive the notification its just regarding the execution of the event. Please let me know if there is any other event required for it
 See the code snippet below

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
  console.log(notification); **//prints only when I click on the notification**
  console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: Try ionic push api that uses phonegap push plugin http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-overview

Comment: @Raj Yes that is a alternative but rather I would prefer to use Cordova,  can you help out in Cordova?

Comment: are you testing on iOS or android?

Comment: android...it worked now, need to set content available:1 on server side while sending notification. Thanks!!